# How to way to make a BusinessHourField for business directory django project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am working on a business directory in django and am trying to figure out the best method for representing a store's business hours, with an open and close time for each day of the week.

So far the options that I have been unsatisfied are:
- Use one CommaSeparatedIntegerField to hold versions of the times in one parseable unit, but I'd rather deal with time objects if I can, with their various attributes and such.

- Explicitly create a TimeField for each day's open and close, but this just sounds like a terrible idea that would take time and be too complicated.
- Build a ScheduleField that would handle it, but then I am sort of unclear on the best road for relating to a pre-existing model field or work with the database.

I know any of you can beat any of those. Care to share?